# How can I work around this error in handling continuous variables in tbl_continuous for gtsummary

Tags: r, statistics, gtsummary

When I try to make a tbl_continuous I am unable to properly summarize continuous by continuous variables. Example below, you can see it inappropriately converts to a factor:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)
#> #StandWithUkraine

tbl_continuous(
    data = trial,
    variable = age,
    include = c(trt, grade, ttdeath)
) %>% add_p()
```

Any direction is appreciated!

I tried to make it in reprex, but it was not looking correct. I also posted it to Git Hub.

Edit: Table I have

| Characteristic | N | p-value |
| --- | --- | --- |

vs one desired:

| Characteristic | R2 | p-value |
| --- | --- | --- |

That way I could describe the relationship of continuous and factors for a continuous pair. I understand they may not merge well but I am happy to separate them. Hope that clarifies, thank you @Ben for the table instructions!

Comment: Can you update your post with an example of what you want the results to look like? The function is working as intended

Comment: Ideally the continuous variable would stay continuous, tested either by pearson or something of that sort. Separating each level of the numeric is what I see currently!

Comment: @Ben I totally understand that including a goal table would help, but if i knew how to make one I wouldn't be posting here lol! here is a link to what my table looks like: https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary/issues/1586   you can see time to death is split up, where I am more interested in if they correlate rather than each individual level being treated as a factor. does that make sense? I can elaborate more if not.

Comment: Oh thats an interesting thought on having it be a footnote, say you were to do it in my example. Would you somehow collapse the factor levels and just manually compute elsewhere then add in as a footnote?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can add the correlation coefs to the table. Note that you should use `modify_footnote()` to update the footnotes to reflect what is now present in the table.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

# build base table
tbl_base <-
  tbl_continuous(
    data = trial,
    variable = age,
    include = c(trt, grade)
  ) %>% 
  add_p()

# these are the underlying column names
show_header_names(tbl_base)
#> ℹ As a usage guide, the code below re-creates the current column headers.
#> modify_header(
#>   label = '**Characteristic**',
#>   stat_0 = '**N = 200**',
#>   p.value = '**p-value**'
#> )
#> 
#> 
#> Column Name   Column Header      
#> ------------  -------------------
#> label         **Characteristic** 
#> stat_0        **N = 200**        
#> p.value       **p-value**

# build a data frame with matching colnames as the base table
df_pearson <- 
  cor.test(trial$ttdeath, trial$age) |> 
  broom::tidy() |> 
  select(estimate, p.value) |> 
  mutate(
    stat_0 = round(estimate, 3) |> as.character(),
    variable = "ttdeath", 
    label = "Time to Death, months"
  )

# add correlation results to the base table
tbl_base |> 
  modify_table_body(
    ~.x |> bind_rows(df_pearson)
  ) |> 
  as_kable() # convert to kable to present on stackoverflow
```

| **Characteristic** | **N = 200** | **p-value** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chemotherapy Treatment |  | 0.7 |
| Drug A | 46 (37, 59) |  |
| Drug B | 48 (39, 56) |  |
| Grade |  | 0.8 |
| I | 47 (37, 56) |  |
| II | 49 (37, 57) |  |
| III | 47 (38, 58) |  |
| Time to Death, months | -0.051 | 0.5 |

```r
# use modify_footnote() to update the footnotes to reflect what's presented in the table
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>